# Commutations relations of C,P,T transformations with Lorentz group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, parity, time-reversal-symmetry, charge-conjugation

Almost any QFT textbook discusses the C,P,T symmetry operators which are charge conjugation, parity transformation, time reversal respectively.

> I failed so far to find any discussion of the commutation relations of these operators with the Lorentz group (or its generators). I would be happy to have a reference.

Comment: Weinberg covers this, of course.

Comment: @Oбжорoв: Could you please refer to the exact place in Weinberg's book where he computes the commutation relations between charge conjugation and a boost.

Comment: Volume chapter 2 if my recollection is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Weinberg vol 1 Eqs (2.6.7) to (2.6.12) for $P$ and $T$.

Comment: Pls accept the answer if you can. Tx.